# How do you bosonise the spin-$1/2$ operator $S_z$?

Tags: condensed-matter, bosonization, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

Consider a 1D spin-$1/2$ chain. After a [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation), the spin-$1/2$ operator $S^z_i$ takes the form

$$ S^z_i = c^\dagger_i c_i - \frac{1}{2} \equiv \rho_i - \frac{1}{2}$$

where $\{ c_i \}$ are a set of fermionic modes obeying $\{ c_i,c_j^\dagger \} = \delta_{ij}$ and $\{ c_i,c_j \} = \{ c_i^\dagger, c_j^\dagger \} = 0$ and $\rho_i = c^\dagger_i c_i$ is the density operator.

### Bosonising

The first step to bosonise a theory is to work in the continuum limit and expand the fermionic modes $c_i$ about the two Fermi points $\pm k_F$ as

$$ c_i = e^{ik_F x_i} \psi_R(x_i) + e^{-ik_F x_i} \psi_L(x_i)$$

Substituting this into the expression for $S^z_i$, we would arrive at

$$ S^z_i=\rho_L(x_i) + \rho_R(x_i) + (e^{-2ik_Fx_i} \psi^\dagger_R(x_i) \psi_L(x_i) + \mathrm{h.c.} ) - \frac{1}{2}$$

where $\rho_{L,R} = \psi^\dagger_{L,R} \psi_{L,R}$.

Now in Eq. (6.32) of Quantum Physics in One Dimension by Giamarchi, the author ignored the factor of $1/2$, essentially saying that when we bosonise we can assume $S_i^z = \rho_i$. Why can I just do this? This extra factor of $1/2$ seems to be important if I was looking at something like the interaction in the $XXZ$ model: the interaction coinsists of the terms

$$ S^z_i S^z_{i+1} = (\rho_i - 1/2)(\rho_{i+1} - 1/2) = \rho_i \rho_{i+1} - \frac{1}{2} ( \rho_i + \rho_{i+1}) + \frac{1}{4} $$

However, again in Giamarchi the author has assumed the factor of $1/2$ is not there in the expression for $S^z_i$, so writes in Eq. (6.18)

$$S_i^z S^z_{i+1} = \rho_i \rho_{i+1}  $$

This seems to be a huge simplification here as we have thrown away non-trivial density terms.

### My question

Why are we allowed to assume that $S_i^z = c^\dagger_i c_i$ when we bosonise this operator?

Comment: if i remember correctly, for proper bosonization you assume you are around half-filling. that is, you start with $\langle c^{\dagger}_i c_i \rangle = 1/2$ and then expand about this point to get the linear spectrum of the bosonic theory. so the $1/2$ factor is "swallowed" into the ground state. basically you do the transformation $\tilde{\rho}_i = \rho_i - 1/2$ (this is not an answer but a comment because i'm not sure about that and probably it needs a better formalism)

Comment: @yyy is right. In fact what it means is $S_z=:\rho :$ where $:\rho :$ is normal ordered , namely the vacuum expectation has been subtracted.